# Coq: How to use one tactic to appoint instances for multiple existential quantified variables

Tags: coq-tactic

Suppose I have a goal as follow.

```
exists s0 s3 s4 : list T, s1 ++ s2 = s0 ++ s3 ++ s4
```

I want to appoint some concrete values for `s0, s3, s4` and I am trying `exists v1 v2 v3` to do that with `v1 v2 v3` already in the proof context. But coq complains that

```
Not the right number of missing arguments (expected 1)
```

So I have to use three tactics to do this.

```
exists v1. exists v2. exists v3.
```

I want to known if it's possible to use just one tactic to get the same result. Many thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `exists v1, v2, v3.`  I just tested with coq-8.13.2